# Eclipse Data Source Explorer : SQL Scrapbook

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-3.4

Is it possible to open an SQL scrapbook with the Data Source Explorer in Eclipse 3.4+? I found this on how to open a [SQL Scrapbook in Database Explorer](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/RDBTutorial/RDBTutorial.html) which applys to eclipse 3.2+, but doesn't seem to be supported in the latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's there. You need the [Data Tools Project](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_Started_with_DTP) plugin.